# Dense linear span and dual's dimension

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm having trouble with these results:

> 1.Prove that the dimension of the dual space of an infinite dimensional normed space is infinite.
>
> 2.Let $A \subset X$ where $X$ is a normed space. Prove that $\overline{span{A}}=X$ $\iff$ $\forall f \in X^{*} $(except $f \equiv 0$)  exists $x\in A$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$

I put both of them together since they seem to be corollaries of Hahn-Banach's Theorem. However, I'm not able to prove them. I'd appreciate any hint or solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi sorry. I was completely lost. I wouldn't have even known how to start. Anyway, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let $Y$ be an infinite dimensional normed space. Hahn-Banach says for every subspace $X_n\subseteq Y$, $\dim X_n=n$ we have a surjective linear mapping $Y^\ast\to X_n^\ast$ by restriction. So $\dim Y^\ast \geq n$ forall $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
2. Let $span A$ be dense in $X$. Suppose there ist $0\neq f\in X^\ast$ with $f(x)=0$ forall $x\in A$. Then $f(x)=0$ forall $x\in span A$ and because $f$ is continous we have the contradiction $f=0$.
   If $span A$ isn't dense in $X$, we look at the canonic map $\pi\colon X\to X/\overline{span A}$. We get with Hahn-Banach $0\neq \tilde{f}\in (X/\overline{span A})'$ and so $f=\circ \tilde{f}\circ \pi$ is a nontrivial functional with $f_{|\overline{span A}}=0$.